# When the DOM of element exists after ng-if become true?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm very new to angularjs.

I'm using ng-if to hide/show the portion of html code

```
<div ng-if="editing">
    <textarea id="editor" ng-model="longtext"></textarea>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to access to DOM of textarea to modify it(using CKeditor).

```
$scope.edit=function(){
    $scope.editing = true
    $("#editor").ckEditor({})
}
```

The problem is the textarea is not exists at this point. 
I can use `setTimeout` and it's works but I don't think it's a clean way to do.
How do do this in a cleaner way?

I made fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wxB36/2/ (I use addClass instead of ckEditor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to wrap ckeditor in a directive, because it is a re-usable component that needs to do its own DOM manipulation and eventing.

And it looks like there is [already a project on github](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor) for this.

If you use the directive, then the `ng-if` will work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ng-show`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) instead:

```
<textarea id="editor" ng-model="longtext" ng-show="editing"></textarea>
```

The difference is that the textarea is always in the DOM, but hidden by CSS when `$scope.editing` is false.